# Reliable source for getting information about bringing medication

Tags: health

When I travel to another country, I sometimes need to bring some medication that I occasionally have to take.
But some medications may be strictly prohibited or restricted to bring in or sometimes may be allowed under certain circumstances such as with a doctor's prescription.

Is there a reliable source to get what kind of limitation exists for specific countries such as the United States, France, or Italy?

Comment: I don't believe there's any centralized resource, you need to deal with each country's authorities individually.

Comment: In general no, but from my experience, on most immigration/custom sites you will find a prominent warning about not importing some drugs (also with prescriptions), e.g. on opioids, so your "strictly prohibited". It is usually in the standard rules about what I can import (I look them about importing cheese as gifts). So: be sure to look that and to comply. The details could be practically impossible to find (it could not be written in law, but decided by some medical authority, and with complex forms (day X added Y, etc.) and in local language.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is no centralized resource, so it would be better to gather information here. I will update it.
(Last update: September 26, 2023)

https://www.incb.org/incb/en/travellers/country-regulations.html

## Information for travelers with medicine

They are all official government websites otherwise marked with * after the country name.

## Africa

Egypt *: https://www.egyptadventurestravel.com/blog/can-i-bring-my-prescription-to-egypt

## Americas

Canada: https://travel.gc.ca/travelling/health-safety/medication

Mexico *: https://mx.usembassy.gov/bringing-items-into-mexico-u-s/
https://www.mexadventure.com/mexico-travel/bringing_medication_to_mexico.cfm

United States: https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1160?language=en_US

## Asia

India *: https://www.tajtravel.com/blog/traveling-india-with-medication

Japan: https://www.mhlw.go.jp/english/policy/health-medical/pharmaceuticals/01.html

Singapore: https://www.hsa.gov.sg/personal-medication/

South Korea: https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/nl-en/brd/m_20932/view.do?seq=4&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&

Taiwan: https://www.roc-taiwan.org/us_en/post/6849.html

## Europe

France: https://www.douane.gouv.fr/fiche/private-individuals-carrying-medicinal-products-france

Germany: https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Restrictions/Medicinal-products-and-narcotics/medicinal-products-and-narcotics_node.html

Italy: https://www.salute.gov.it/portale/medicinaliStupefacenti/dettaglioContenutiMedicinaliStupefacenti.jsp?lingua=italiano&id=5785&area=sostanzeStupefacenti&menu=sostanze

Spain: https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/washington/en/Embajada/Paginas/FAQ.aspx

Switzerland: https://www.bazg.admin.ch/bazg/en/home/information-individuals/bans--restrictions-and-authorisations/narcotics-and-drugs.html

Turkey *: https://visit-turkey.org/travel-advice/taking-medication-to-turkey

United Kingdom: https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/essential-medicines-and-medical-equipment

Within EU countries: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/health/prescription-medicine-abroad/prescriptions/faq/index_en.htm

## Oceania

Australia: https://www.tga.gov.au/products/travelling-medicines-and-medical-devices

New Zealand: https://www.customs.govt.nz/personal/travel-to-and-from-nz/medicines/